# TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, iteration

I want to iterate through the column `df['fyear']` and delete any row for which `fyear` isn't equal to either 2009, 2019, or 2020. But this error comes up:

`TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fyear': [2009, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2019, 2009, 2000, 2000, 2001]})

for row in df.iterrows():
    if df["fyear"] != 2009 | df["fyear"] !=2019 | df["fyear"] !=2020:
        df.drop(row)
```

**EDIT** The optimal solution is using boolean indexing with either the operators `&` or `|`

```
df = df[(df['fyear'] == 2009) | (df['fyear'] == 2019) | (df['fyear'] == 2020)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python uses `or` as infix keyword

```py
df["fyear"] != 2009 or df["fyear"] !=2019 or df["fyear"] !=2020
```

Or even better (more pythonic and also readable)

```py
df["fyear"] not in (2009,2019,2020)
```

Comment: I've used this solution more than once and it resolved the error. Thank you, @DownloadPizza!